# Converting a table into a counter

Tags: kitchen-counters, table, old-work

I want to take a sentimental (but not expensive) table that my father built my husband and I for our first apartment. He used old spindles from my parents first home and the hardwood . And made a table from it. I want to basically cut the table in half length wise and attach it to my kitchen wall. As a breakfast bar of sorts. 
I imagine I need to build a support onto the wall for the table to attach itself to- as well as some other supports but I'm unsure of exactly what to do. I can cut it- but attaching it is the hard part. Please any advice would be great. I normally ask my father because he's a master craftsman but I want to surprise him with my ingenuity be skills that he has taught me.

Answer (score 1):

A simple 2x2 cut and then mounted to wall so the table half will rest on it.  Then from the underside of the 2x2 attach the table with screws that will pass through the 2x2 but short enough they will not go completely through the table top.

Comment: +1 I would do in exactly same manner. Short screws help to not to do any harm to (visible parts of) the table.